# Edge Browser HTML file Upload not working

Tags: javascript, html, microsoft-edge

Edge Browser HTML file Upload not working if **file name having space**

Basic Code:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_fileupload_get

Run this URL and check in Edge Browser.

If any fix available to this issue. It will be great to share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems that it was a bug of edge (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/8282613/). As i see it is fixed on the latest version, so maybe you have to install this version.